# Android ViewModel observer never gets called

Tags: android, viewmodel, observer-pattern

I am having the following code:

```
public class ViewModelDrivers extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<List<DriverDetailsModel>> drivers;

    public LiveData<List<DriverDetailsModel>> getDrivers() {
        if (drivers == null) {
            drivers = new MutableLiveData<>();
            loadDrivers();
        }
        return drivers;
    }

    private void loadDrivers() {
        CloudFactory.getInstance().getAllServerDrivers(PreferenceUtils.getInstance().getDeviceId(), new IServerAllTrucksCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAllTrucks(List<DriverDetailsModel> d) {
                drivers.setValue(d);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the MainActivity on onCreate method:

```
    ViewModelDrivers model = new ViewModelProvider(this, new ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()).get(ViewModelDrivers.class);

        model.getDrivers().observe(this, items -> {
//here never gets called. Why?
});
```

I didnt used ViewModelProviders since is deprecated. I never received a result in observe() method. Moreover `drivers.setValue(d);` gets set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `drivers.setValue()` to `drivers.postValue(` and if this helps, then you should change your code like **Suraj Vaishnav** defined, calling **loadDrivers** after subscribing to observer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your `drivers.setValue(d);` called before `return drivers;`
So remove `loadDrivers();` from `getDrivers()` method, like this:

```
 public LiveData<List<DriverDetailsModel>> getDrivers() {
        if (drivers == null) {
            drivers = new MutableLiveData<>();
        }
        return drivers;
    }
```

And call `loadDrivers()` from after setting observer, like this:

```
model.getDrivers().observe(this, items -> {
//here never gets called. Why?
});
loadDrivers(); //here call loadDrivers();
```

Comment: moving loadDrivers() to fragment/activity will result bad architecture: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel